# npm run deploy not working properly for react app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify-cli

I am running npm run deploy command but it is stopping after 2 lines without any error and files are not getting updated. I have hosted website on s3. Snapshot shows the 2 lines. It was working fine before. Something happened suddenly. Thanks in advance for the help. [image]

Comment: Could you perhaps post your **deploy** script content? so that we can view and see what is up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting pc solved it. I don't know how.

Answer (score -2):

There are some possible reasons you got the error:

1. Clear npm Cache. Occasionally, issues can arise due to a corrupted npm cache. Try clearing the npm cache and then run the deploy command again:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm run deploy
```

2. Check for Long-Running Processes. If your deployment involves any background processes, ensure that they are completing successfully. Check if there are any long-running processes that might be blocking the deployment.
3. Environmental Variables. If your deployment process relies on environment variables, ensure that they are correctly set and accessible by the deployment script.
4. Review the Deploy Script. Review the deploy script itself to see if there are any issues within the script that might be causing it to halt prematurely.
5. Check Permissions. Ensure that you have the necessary permissions to write/update files in the deployment destination. Permission issues can sometimes cause processes to halt.
6. Network Issues. If your deployment involves fetching or pushing data over the network, ensure you have a stable internet connection and that there are no network-related issues.
7. Run Commands Manually. If the deploy process involves multiple steps or commands, consider running each step manually to narrow down where the issue is occurring.
8. Check Logs. Even if you don't see errors on the console, there might be logs or log files generated during the deploy process. Check those logs for any clues about what might be happening.

Comment: @LW001 I'm pretty sure this is chatgpt. not much point in editing.